# v4l2loopback-ctl version on debian packages

Tags: debian, version, v4l2loopback

I would like to use v4l2loopback on a debian (Bookworm) machine. I've installed v4l2loopback-utils package (version 0.12.7-2) but when i run `v4l2loopback-ctl --version` the result is `0.6`.

I need to use the `add` command of `v4l2loopback-ctl` but this is not available in the 0.6 version. The problem seems to be common on every debian versions (Buster, Bullseye ...). Is it normal that the binary is not updated to the last version (0.12.7) ?

Thanks,
Regards

Answer (score 1):

It’s “normal”, at least it matches what upstream provides: [the v0.12.7 release ships the old `v4l2loopback-ctl` shell script](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/tree/v0.12.7/utils) rather than [the C implementation](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/tree/main/utils). Only the latter includes the commands you’re looking for.

The first step in getting this fixed would be to [open an issue asking for a release with the new version of `v4l2loopback-ctl`](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/new/choose).